# Manually logging database event in datastage job

Tags: etl, datastage, ibm-infosphere

i have a parallel job that writes in oracle table. I want to manually write warnings in Datastage's log if some event occur. For example if a certain value for a certain column is inserted i want to track this information in the log. Could this be achieved somehow?

Answer (score 1):

To write custom messages into the logs for a particular jobs data stream, you can use a combination of a copy stage, transformer, and peak stage. The peak stage is the one that writes to the logs. I like to set the peak stage to run in sequential mode, so that your messages are kept together in single entries in the log, instead across nodes.

[image: Peak data]

Also, you can peak the rejects of the oracle stage. maybe combine this with the above option (using a funnel stage and a standard column schema).

[image: Peak oracle database rejects]

Lastly, if you'd actually like to query the logs themselves and write those logs out somewhere else or use them in a job (amoungst allother data kept about jobs in the repository). You can directly query the DSODB schema in the XMETA database. I.e. the DataStage repository (by default DB2).

You would need to have the DataStage Operations Console up and running for that (not sure what version of DataStage you're running). If DataStage is running on a single tier and using the default DB2 database. You can simply catalog the DSODB database so that it's available as a connection in the DB2 connector. Else you'd need to install a DB2 client on the DataStage engine tier and catalog the database there.

All the best!

Twitter: @InforgeAcademy
DataStage tips and Tricks: https://www.inforgeacademy.com/blog/